# Custom rows in ListView with custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I made the following adapter which I used before to create rows that are the same all the time. I removed the creation of the textviews and imageviews.

What I want to achieve is to create different rows depending on the key.
A row could contain text and an image while another row only has text. How would I be able to do that?

```
public class DetailsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> keys;

    public DetailsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> keys) {
        super(context,R.layout.details); 
        this.context = context;
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, null);      
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return keys.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to inflate different layout for rows?

Comment: Did you try the below??

Comment: Not yet, but I see what I have to do now.

Comment: give it a try it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inflate different layout for rows you need to override `getViewItemType` and `getViewTypeCount`.

You should have a look at the video in the link.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM3 = 2;
```

Then

```
int type;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position== 0){
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;
    } else if  (position == 1){
        type = TYPE_ITEM2;
    }
    else
    {
         type= TYPE_ITEM3 ;
    }
    return type;
}

 @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3; 
 }
@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
LayoutInflater inflater = null;
int type = getItemViewType(position);
  // instead of if else you can use a case
   if (convertView == null) {
    if (type == TYPE_ITEM1 {
            //infalte layout of type1
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layouttype1, 
                         parent, false);
      }
    if (type == TYPE_ITEM2) {
            //infalte layout of type2
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layouttype2, 
                         parent, false);
    }  else {
            //infalte layout of normaltype
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layouttype3, 
                         parent, false);
 }
 ...// rest of the code
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override `getViewTypeCount` inside this function return the number of types views you want to use inside listview.

Override `getItemViewType(int position)` inside this write your logic to get the type of view.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return 2; //return 2, in case you have two types of view
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return (contition) ? R.layout.layout1 : R.layout.layout2; //return 2, in case you have two types of view
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = (convertView == null) ?View.inflate(context, getItemViewType(position), null) : convertView;
    return convertView;
}
```