# ListView Recycling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having a hard time understanding how my specific situation should work regarding recycling views.

I have a list of friends and their names.

If they are online, their name is green.

If they are offline, their name is grey and their photo is half transparent.

If in my adapter I use:

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {                 
    return 1;
}
```

then the views get recycled, and when I scroll someone with a green name out of view and then back in, their name turns grey and their photo becomes half transparent.

**The user's online or offline status is based on a query to the database, so I don't understand how I'm supposed to reset that view with the correct information before it comes back on the screen again.**

Before, I had this:

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {                 

    return getCount();
}
```

and I didn't have the view recycling issue, but the app crashed when a user had 0 friends in their list.

**Any help much appreciated!**

**getView:**

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.fbphoto = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fbphoto);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }



        final HashMap<String,String> item = (HashMap<String,String> ) items.get(position);
        if (item != null)
        {

            String facebookProfilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+item.get(TAG_FACEBOOKID)+"/picture?width=150&height=150";

            Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(facebookProfilePicUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
            .into(holder.fbphoto);

            if ( item.get(TAG_USERNAME).length() > 23 ) {

                holder.name.setText(item.get(TAG_USERNAME).substring(0, Math.min(item.get(TAG_USERNAME).length(), 20)) + "..."); 

                } else {

                    holder.name.setText(item.get(TAG_USERNAME));
                }


            if ("2".equals(item.get(TAG_THEM_ONLINE))) {
                //nothing, will add more later
                } else {
                    holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a7a7a7"));
                    holder.fbphoto.setAlpha(.4f);
                    }


        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

**EDIT: Well, I feel silly. I was dynamically setting the name color, etc for when the user was offline, but only set the colors, etc for online users in xml. Therefore, when the screen reloads the view, it didn't know how to set them properly.**

Comment: post your getview code

Comment: I figured it out! But I wouldn't have if you didn't ask me to post my getview, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have 2 states, offline and online with different colors etc.

you need to return 2 for getViewTypeCount (offline and online)

further you need to implement getViewType, there you need to return 0 or 1 either if the item is online or offline.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isOnline ? 1 : 0;
}
```

for example.

oh and you don't have problems before because you returned the Typecount == the size of your items. Every Item got a different type so you never got any recycled view.

refer to my first answer: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't have a viewTypeCount < 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854861/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cant-have-a-viewtypecount-1)