# load phone contacts with async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, contacts

I am getting the phone contacts and problems are given but when I am using the async task the application stops working.

This is my error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't have a viewTypeCount < 1

I am calling the async task in the onCreate method like so:

`new displayContacts().execute();`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post your adapter's code?

Comment: you can see `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854861/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cant-have-a-viewtypecount-1`

Comment: I updated my answer regarding the contact displayed more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess getViewTypeCount returns the number of different types of views this adapter can return. type of view should just return 1.

```js
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: where should I place this?

Comment: In ModifiedAdapter, and you should show your adapter in question

Comment: ok now it is displaying and every contact is  displayed 3 times example lara lara lara sam sam sam ....

Answer (score -1):

The issue you have is related to your `Adapter` not your `AsyncTask`..

If you override the [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) in your adapter you should make sure you return more than 1. This method is used to know how many view types your list should have.. in your case I guess it'll be one type, instead you're using `getCount()` which eventually could return 0

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // if you have more than 1 view type than make sure it's > 1                 
    return 1;
}
```

You're also querying `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` which contains the phone numbers.. so if a user has 3 entries in that table you'll list will contains 3 times the same name.. you should query `ContactsContract.Contacts`

Refer to this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) to better understand  the contact provider.

You find here [how to retrieve contacts list](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) according to the official documentation.